# Exactly match query in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I created an Express.js MongoDB API that filters products based on the filter property, the problem is that I want to make this API output exactly match the filter property. but currently for example if product A has `[{name: 'a', value: '1'}, {name: 'b', value: '2'}]` and product B has `[{name: 'a', value: '1'}, {name: 'c', value: '3'}]` and if I pass the data to the API like `[{name: 'a', value: '1'}, {name: 'b', value: '2'}]`, it returns product B too, because it has `{name: 'a', value: '1'}` as a value inside filter property. How can I make my query exactly match based on passed values?

this is product schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { s, rs, rn, rref, ref, b } = require('../utils/mongo');

let schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: rref('user'),
    name: rs,
    description: s,
    images: [s],
    price: rn,
    categories: ref('category'),
    filters: [
      {
        parent: ref('filter'),
        value: s,
        name: s,
      },
    ],
    subFilter: [
      {
        parent: s,
        value: s,
        title: s,
      },
    ],
    published: b,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('product', schema);
```

and this is my query:

```
filter: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { categories, filters } = req.body;
      let products;

      if (filters.length > 0) {
        let targ_cat = categories;
        let any_one_of = filters;

        let or_list = [];

        any_one_of.forEach(function (f) {
          or_list.push({
            $and: [
              { $eq: [f['name'], '$$this.name'] },
              { $eq: [f['value'], '$$this.value'] },
            ],
          });
        });
        let or_expr = { $or: or_list };

        products = await Product.aggregate([
          { $match: { categories: new ObjectId(targ_cat) } },
          {
            $addFields: {
              filters: { $filter: { input: '$filters', cond: or_expr } },
            },
          },
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: { $gt: [{ $size: '$filters' }, 0] },
            },
          },
        ]);
      } else {
        products = await Product.find({ categories });
      }

      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
```

this one is what I want to send as body to the API

````
{
  category: '62445c3d922d127512867245'
  filters: [
    { name: 'filter name 1', value: '62445c3d922d127512861236' },
    { name: 'filter name 2', value: '62445c3d922d127512861458' },
    .....
  ]
}```
````

Comment: Use of  `or_list` and `any_one_of` looks a bit weird, if you want to find documents that match all criteria, not "any one of". When you need "all" matches, you use  `$and`. When you need "at least one" match you use `$or`.

Comment: this code is related to 3 weeks ago, and now we decided to change it to exactly match, even I changed the $or to $and it doesn't return anything, I don't know how to fix it honestly

Comment: hmm, what's the point to post the code that even not supposed to do what you want. Sorry, but it looks more like a request for free labour. Consider updating the snippet to align it with the question. There are many people who wouldn't mine to give a helping hand, but such discrepancy between the text and the code puts them off.  You see, one thing is to spot a mistake, and another is to rewrite everything.

Comment: It wouldn't harm if you put some efforts to isolate the problem - whether the pipeline you generate is not what you expect, or the query returns unexpected result. The former is pure javascript, so you can skip mongodb part altogether, the later is purely aggregation question, which doesn't require all the express logic around it. Just leave the pipeline, the documents, and the result. The simpler the question the more people will jump to the plyground to help you.

Comment: in question, I said that currently, this API returns any one of the filters... I believe that it's clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `find` for exact match:

```
db.collection.find({
  category: "62445c3d922d127512867245",
  filters: [
    {
      name: "filter name 1",
      value: "62445c3d922d127512861236"
    },
    {
      name: "filter name 2",
      value: "62445c3d922d127512861458"
    }
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RbN28rGJptr)

Comment: did you see the schema? I wanna make a query between product filters property

Comment: Yes. Why are you asking?

Comment: product has filters property and I want to make a query to filter products based on their filters and categories props. also, filters prop has parent that I don't pass the parent to the query

Comment: `const { categories, filters } = req.body;`

Comment: I suggest you will add sample docs, specific query input and expected results for this data and input

Comment: I edited my question, I added what I send as a body to the API

Comment: So, you can use a simple find, as I said

Comment: dude, filters objects include `parent` props too and it will not work with a simple find method

Comment: See how it doesn't work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ndStrK61Qxp